# Creation of views based on roles in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

If i assign two users to two roles,let's say CSM and sales rep. If I am the sales rep and I go to the campaigns tab and click on the Direct mail view to view records of type Direct mail,I will get a result set. Now if the CSM user tries to access the same view by clicking on the Direct mail view again he should be able to access a different set i.e different set of records of the type direct mail. How do I achieve this. This is of top priority in my task now.Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You could create two views with the same name then make them each visible to the appropriate set of users.

You need to create two **Views**, one that corresponds to each of the groups.  For simplicity, you can name the Views the same thing so long as the Unique Name is, obviously, unique.  I would recommend something like `Direct_Mail_Sales` and `Direct_Mail_CSM` for the unique names.

Set up the criteria for the views however you'd like.

When you get to the bottom of the configuration for each view, make sure to select "Visible to certain **groups of users**" and select the corresponding **Role** from the list.  This will make sure that the view is only visible to the appropriate role.

Since The views have the same name, it will appear to the end user to be the same view.